# Internship in USA (or other country) for my last year of Engineering

Tags: job-search, united-states, internship

I am 21 years old French citizen and studying in an Engineering School, which is a master grade and i'm finishing my 4th year.
My specialization is Information System (I think the equivalent in USA is Computer Science), and for my last year i am studying more in depth Cybersecurity.

My 2 first years was composed of Physics, Mathematics and Computer Science (with soft skills lessons too and 2 languages).

On my 3rd year I went abroad for one semester to London where I had some basics for AI for example. Then back in France I had more mathematics/Physics/IT.
Actually i'm doing a 4 month internship in a big French company working on Communication and Security. I have multiple experiences on internships or contract job as a developper.

Next year i have to do a 6 month internship starting on February/March (But i can also do a V.I.E. which is a contract based job for a french company in foreign countries, and longer than 6 months).

And i would like to do make this internship in a foreign country and especially USA (N.Y. or SF would be nice but looking for suggestions).

The question is : Do i have my chances to find an internship ?

Where do i have to look ? I did some research on SE/LinkedIn but i don't know if there are any other ways.

And another question : Is an internship income enough to live in USA ? In France internship are poor paid in comparison to an engineer doing the same job so i don't know.

Comment: This doesn't seen like the right place to put this, try r/cscareerquestionsEU on reddit or other similar subreddits, they will be happy to help

Comment: You'll need a J1 Visa - the company will have to sponsor you. With many internships in the USA, you'll be doing well to get *any* income. If they do pay you, it's not going to be enough to live on (especially on the west or east coast).

Comment: Usually when I hear Information System, I think Management of Information Systems. It depends on the contents of your program. But I would just recommend you apply to internship roles. in US, engineering internships tend to be paid and some internship programs offer free housing or housing stipend.

Comment: @jcmack Thanks a lot for your answers. For the program, i had Management of Information System but it was only one lesson i had for one semester for example.
Do you think i have my chances as a junior to get the visa sponsored ? On which websites should i look on? Which company i should aim? Just looked a bit for google and they have high expectations.

Comment: @PeteCon Do i have my chances to have the visa? Or  i am not enough "attractive" for the company ? Do you recommend any website to begin my research ? Well i hope i will be able to find what i want, and it would be better if paid :D

Answer (score 2):

I realize that this is not a complete answer, but speaking from experience it is fully possible to obtain a living-wage internship in the USA, although my university certainly made it easier to arrange this. Because companies ask my school for students for 4 month work terms, I had a pool of companies that I knew wanted me or a peer and for that reason I cannot tell you where to look.

What I can tell you is, several USA companies are looking for foreign interns and would gladly take you, especially since 6 months is longer than 4 months.

However, as far as the rest goes:

I am 19 years old studying engineering at a Canadian school and am currently on my third 4 month work term. I am in Washington state, and have friends that are currently in the same situation but in San Francisco. Pay for us is more than enough to live through the term and contributes to a large part of our tuition.

As a comment stated, you will need the company to sponsor you for a J1 Visa.

TL;DR: Yes, you have a good chance at finding an American internship, I don't know where you can look, but specific companies' webpages are a good place to start, and yes those internships may be paid.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the answer. 
Do you think being a Canadian citizen helped you to find the job ? Because your university helped you and i don't know if alone it is feasible.

Because i though of top tier companies but i don't think i meet their expectations (which are very high).

Comment: @RaphaelLopes Being a Canadian citizen wasn't the directly helpful part, although I'm sure that our close ties with the USA didn't hurt things. The helpful part is that my co-op program is globally respected and therefore made the search easier for me. Trust me, as an intern, you can apply with an eagerness to learn the things that you do not know; that is, after all, the point of an internship. My current job is probably considered EE and I have had very few related courses. The companies recognize that they get labour in exchange for giving you learning opportunities.

Comment: Thanks, i'll keep searching. Just signed in in repher.me, hoping someone would refer me.

Answer (score 1):

> And another question : Is an internship income enough to live in USA ?
>   In France internship are poor paid in comparison to an engineer doing
>   the same job so i don't know.

In the US how well an intern is paid depends on the industry and major.  Thus "unpaid internships" making the news every now and then.

Engineering interns, including software, are (or at least should be) well paid.  You'd get more as an experienced engineer with a degree but by intern standards you're the top of the heap.

> I am 21 years old French citizen and studying in an Engineering
>   School, which is a master grade and... for my last year...

So you're about to graduate with a Masters Degree.  Congratulations.

This is your most serious/important internship.  Ideally (both from your and your company's perspective) this should be viewed as a multiple-month interview with a job offer at the end.

So the real questions should be:  Where do you want to work?  Live?

Figure that out, then apply there.

And yes, you'll need sponsorship if it's at the US so it will have to be for a company that sponsors for junior roles.  On the other hand software is extremely in demand and there are an absurd number of unfilled jobs so there's that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailled answer, it helped me a lot.
I understand perfectly the importance of this internship, in my school in my field more than 80% of the students getting hired directly after the internship.
To  be honest i would like to love in France, espacially Paris, but i want to travel and since i went to SF i would like to live few years there even if France got advantages too. USA got income advantage tho.
i would like to stay after the internship for 1 year for example but i have things left in france (gf mostly) and i fear the consequences. 
Sorry for the long post.

Comment: Should i search as student or Junior? Considering after this internship i won't study anymore.

Comment: @RaphaelLopes RE: "after this internship i won't study".  For my company that would mean you'd need to apply for a normal full time job and not an internship, i.e. all interns have to be students after their internship ends... however I think that's a rule the company inflicts on itself.

Comment: In France even if the internship "close" your Master you still have to do an internship. My school ask for an internship close and not a FTE sadly

Answer (score 1):

I think you have your chances, however you have to start looking from now. 
If I understood well, you are studying in an INSA/UT school. 
The good thing is, compared to other candidates from French schools, you have more experience. 
Finding an internship in US will definitely open you doors there. 
Keep looking on SE and other platforms.

The most efficient tool you have now is your network, ask your school's teachers and alumni (!!). You can even ask on US labs websites.

I am not sure the VIE is fully compatible with your school's regulations but it is a real chance. There are a lot of offers on civiweb, go for it !

Bon courage

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer ! :D
Not from Insa/UT but still i think i have more experience than most of other french candidates.
I did not thinked about alumni, i will try this way. For the school teachers, i already talked with some of them and they have few path, but mostly in countries like Singapour or in Dubai.
For the VIE, i talked with previous students and we can do one, we just have to do make a review with teacher and tutor at the end of 6 month. And i found some very interesting offers but i don't know if the income is enough for Bay Area to live.